# Populating Gridview from JSON response I am getting NullPointerException in logcat

Tags: android, json, gridview

I am getting Null point exception in logcat as i was trying for `GridView` from JSON response can anyone solve this. I am new to android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GridView mListView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

        String strUrl = "http://globalringtools.com/android/categories.php";
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
        mListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    }   
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
        }       
        return data;        
    }
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        String data = null;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url){
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
            listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
        }
    }   
    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{
        JSONObject jObject;
        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson){
            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
                countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
            }       
            CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;
            try{
                countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject); 
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            String[] from = { "flag","country"};
            int[] to = { R.id.picture,R.id.text};
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.grid_layout, from, to);
             return adapter;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter){
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();
                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
            }
        }
    }
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{
        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm){
            InputStream iStream=null;
            String im;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");
            URL url;
            try{
                url = new URL(imgUrl);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);
                fOutStream.flush();
                fOutStream.close();
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());
                hmBitmap.put("position",position);
                return hmBitmap;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result){
            String path = (String) result.get("flag");
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");
            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);
            hm.put("flag",path);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Json parser class

```
    package com.ambilobes.cust_grid;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/** A class to parse json data */
public class CountryJSONParser {

    // Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
    public List<HashMap<String,Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        JSONArray jCountries = null;
        try {
            // Retrieves all the elements in the 'countries' array
            jCountries = jObject.getJSONArray("categories");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
        // where each json object represent a country
        return getCountries(jCountries);
    }

    private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCountries(JSONArray jCountries){
        int countryCount = jCountries.length();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> country = null;

        // Taking each country, parses and adds to list object
        for(int i=0; i<countryCount;i++){
            try {
                // Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country
                country = getCountry((JSONObject)jCountries.get(i));
                countryList.add(country);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        return countryList;
    }

    // Parsing the Country JSON object
    private HashMap<String, Object> getCountry(JSONObject jCountry){

        HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String countryName = "";
        String flag="";
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.append("http://globalringtools.com/flowborn/template/resources/images/client_categories");

        try {
            strBuilder.append(jCountry.getString("image"));
            flag = strBuilder.toString();
            countryName = jCountry.getString("category");
            country.put("country", countryName);
            country.put("flag", R.drawable.blank);
            country.put("flag_path", flag);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return country;
    }
}
```

I was trying for Gridview from json and i am getting null point exception..
Can anyone help me.

Comment: Please put your logcat detail.

Comment: 01-23 10:07:59.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 10:07:59.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28335): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 10:07:59.358: E/AndroidRuntime(28335):  at com.ambilobes.cust_grid.MainActivity$ImageLoaderTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:145)

Comment: Nobody knows !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: can you show in your code where exactly means on which line null pointer is coming.

Comment: com.ambilobes.cust_grid.MainActivity$ImageLoaderTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:145)

Comment: Can you specify the code on the line no 145?

Comment: http://globalringtools.com/flowborn/template/resources/images/client_categoriescoffeeshops.jpg file not found. Can't download image file that's why give null pointer exception in onPostExecution - result is null.

Comment: @ officebrain from  
globalringtools.com/flowborn/template/resources/images/client_categories/ url i am apending image name from json also..... like casualsformen.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is on line 145 in your ImageLoaderTask is the problem. Is the response not null? The website your trying to hit may be null.

```
protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result){
  if (result != null) {
  ...
  }
}
```

The following code is failing.

```
try{
                url = new URL(imgUrl);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);
                fOutStream.flush();
                fOutStream.close();
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());
                hmBitmap.put("position",position);
                return hmBitmap;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Something is throwing an exception, you should either step through the code or at least log the exception using `Log.e("Exception",e);`

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: Your code worked me fine...Thanks... Actually I dont know how to promote you in stack. Tell me that tooo

Comment: You should click the check mark beside my answer to make it green. This will show people that you accept answer which will make people more willing to help in the future. Full instructions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
 DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
 downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
 mListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
```

here your `DownloadTask` is executing before your initialize `GridView`. So your error will be this line. So need to move this line  `mListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);` before your `DownloadTask`  is execute. So it will be

```
mListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
```

Comment: So are you getting same problem still??? Show me the line at where you getting error?

Comment: Image is not displaying in Gridview

Comment: But app crashing? And if it crashed show me that line

Comment: Now my app is not crashing.. Image is not displaying!!

Comment: For displaying image use universal image loader class. And after using my code not app is not crashing?

Comment: The same above code is working fine for me for the listview ....In case of grid view only it is not diplaying...My app stop crashing becuase i just add protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result){
  if (result != null) {} as suggested by Mark Hetherington.. Can u please help me